# How to parse xml files with nokogiri and put the results in a new file?

Tags: xml, ruby, nokogiri

I'm just beginning with Nokogiri and have a question, hope you guys can help me out:

1. I need to parse a set of XML files (let's say 5 files).
2. Find elements with specific values, for instance, City = "London" using XPATH.
3. Create a new XML file, that contains the results of the previous XPATH query in Step 2

Comment: When asking you need to either show code you've written, or explain where you've searched and what you tried and why it didn't help you. As is this question is very broad and doesn't show any effort or research and in general won't help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 19):

The following makes a few assumptions about your situation that may be incorrect (namely, that "city" is a node and not an attribute, and that all the files are in a single directory), but you should be able to tweak it to suit your needs.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

Dir.glob("*.xml").each do |filename|
  input = Nokogiri::XML(File.new(filename))
  output = Nokogiri::XML::Document.new
  output.root = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new("output", output)
  input.root.xpath("//*[city='London']").each {|n| output.root << n}
  File.open("out_" + filename, 'w') {|f| f.write(output.to_xml) }
end
```